# rails 5 method fails as before_save method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a method (`count_dupes`) that runs fine in console in this manner:

```
@u = User.first
@c = @u.collections.first
[output of that find]
@c.count_dupes
[output]
@c.save!
[output followed by true]
```

The basic setup is as follows:

- A user `has_many` collections;
- A collection `has_many` items;
- A collection `has_many :dupe_items, class_name: 'Item', foreign_key:
  'collection_dupe_id'`

the `count_dupes` method (from collection model):

```
def count_dupes
  self.items.includes(:collection).each do |item|
    threshold = item.holdback.presence || item.collection.holdback
    if item.quantity > threshold
      dupes_qty = item.quantity - threshold
      item.collection_dupe_id = item.collection_id
      item.dupe_quantity = dupes_qty
      item.save!
    end
  end
end
```

When I have this set in a before_save method on collection, it fails with a stack level too deep. Removing `.includes(:collection)` lets it run, but this takes forever on each object and has thousands of lines like this:

```
CACHE Collection Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "collections" WHERE "collections"."name" = $1 AND ("collections"."id" != $2) AND "collections"."user_id" = 1 LIMIT $3  [["name", "Wahunsenekah (333B)"], ["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
```

There are still hundreds of this after adding the .includes(:collection) statement, but far fewer than before.

Schema for Item:

```
create_table "items", id: :serial, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name", limit: 255
    t.string "location", limit: 255
    t.text "description"
    t.date "acquired_on"
    t.decimal "price"
    t.integer "issue_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer "collection_id"
    t.integer "quantity"
    t.integer "holdback"
    t.integer "collection_dupe_id"
    t.integer "dupe_quantity", default: 0
    t.index ["collection_id"], name: "index_items_on_collection_id"
    t.index ["issue_id"], name: "index_items_on_issue_id"
  end
```

I'm sure this is something that is staring me in the face and I'm just unable to see it, but weeks of slicing this from different angles in my free time and I'm at a loss.

Comment: can you show put a breakpoint in there, trigger the infinite loop, and show the output of `backtrace`? That will show where the infinite loop is coming from.

Comment: Maybe it is `threshold = item.holdback.presence || item.collection.holdback`? This line is inside an instance method for Collection, so you don't need to find `item.collection`, you need to use `self`

Comment: @maxpleaner I think what you're looking for is this:

    `app/models/collection.rb:93:in 'block in count_dupes'
    app/models/collection.rb:86:in 'count_dupes'`

That repeats a bunch after the ROLLBACK is issued. The method starts on line 85

Comment: Do you have any callbacks for dupe_items?  Is the save! in count_dupes calling before_save and ininitely looping?

Comment: @bkunzi01dupe_item is item, and that model has no callback hooks at all. The only callback hook on Collection (where count_dupes method lives) is the before_save that calls count_dupes. The relationship does have autosave: true on it, however: Collection `has_many :items, inverse_of: :collection, dependent: :destroy, autosave: true`

Comment: @bkunzi01 Looks like this was the culprit. Took out `autosave: true` on both sides of the relationship and it now processes correctly